# Setting the width of a RichCombo box in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I've created a plugin with a `RichCombo` box. Unfortunately the name of the dropdown is a little too long for the `RichCombo` and it gets cut off.

[image]

Is there a way to force a wider `RichCombo`? Likewise, is there a way to force a width of the actual dropdown list (`ListBox`) itself?

Comment: You can write a css rule that targets the element.

Comment: thanks, I figured out how to target the button but not the list itself. in the plugin I can set a className but this does not affect the listbox?

Comment: It should be something like `html .cke_combopanel { width: auto; }` Been awhile since I styled one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSS value you seek is `.cke_combopanel { width: 150px; }`. It can be found within `editor.css`.

Comment: I have changed every instance of .cke_combopanel in editor.css, to no avail.  Any other suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: PS.  Why isn't the default 'auto'?

Comment: Sorry, no other suggestions. I think that your best bet is to play around with the Developer tools (F12) in your browser. I know that focusing on an open combopanel is hard to do, but you can do it after experimenting a bit. Seeing what value is actually used for the width makes development much easier. I haven't used CKE in a long time now, so for modern versions of CKE my answer might be obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

style your page with:

```css
.cke_combo_text  {
  width: 130px !important;
}
.cke_combopanel {
  width: 370px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it.  I added this to the page containing the ckeditor control:

```
<style>
    .cke_combo_text { width:auto !important; }
    .cke_combopanel { height:600px !important; }
</style>
```